Show Sp(1) is the same as SU(2)
I'm reading John Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory but got stuck at a result in section 3.4 when he began introducing the symplectic groups.
He defined the symplectic groups as the following:
On the space $\mathbb{H}^n$ of ordered n-tuples of quaternions there is a natural inner product $(p_1,...,p_n) \cdot (q_1,...,q_n)= p_1 \bar{q_1} + ... + p_n \bar{q_n}$, where $p_i$ and $q_j$ are arbitrary quaternions and bar represents the quaternion conjugate.
$Sp(n)$ is the group of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{H}$ that preserves such inner product.
Then he claimed that as $Sp(1)$ consists of the quaternions that preserve length in $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{R}^4$, these are precisely the unit quaternions, hence $SU(2)$.
I tried to verify the claim by using the definition above: suppose $u \in Sp(1)$ is some quaternion that preserves the 1-fold inner product. That means for any $p,q \in \mathbb{H}$, $(up)\cdot (uq) =up \overline{(uq)} =up \bar{q} \bar{u}= (p)\cdot (q)= p \bar{q}$. Taking $p=q=1$, we know that $u \bar{u}=1$ so $u$ must be a unit quaternion and $\bar{u} = u^{-1}$. This is fine.
However, I don't quite see how the backward argument would work. There is a result in an earlier part of the book says: "for a unit quaternion $t = cos\theta + u\cdot sin\theta$, where $u\in Im(\mathbb{H})$ is a unit vector, then conjugation by $t$ rotates $Im(\mathbb{H})$ through angle $2\theta$ about axis $u$." (This is the connection between $\mathbb{H}$ and $SO(3)$.)
Now if $p \bar{q}$ lands in $Im(\mathbb{H})$ and it's not invariant under the conjugation of unit quaternion $u$, we will have $up \bar{q} \bar{u}= up \bar{q} u^{-1} \neq p \bar{q}$. Hence the 1-fold inner product is not preserved by multiplication of $u$. Does this indicate that $Sp(1)$ is strictly contained in $SU(2)$?
Aside: I looked at my proof for $U(1) \cong SO(2)$ and realised this is true because complex numbers are commutative; and in general, a matrix $M$ preserves the Hermitian inner product iff $M^{\dagger}M=I$ is due to $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$, which also boils down to the commutativity of $\mathbb{C}$, a luxury we don't have when working with quaternions.
I guess my ultimate confusion is, how to show $M^{\dagger}M = I$ iff $M$ preserves the symplectic inner product (as defined above), where $M$ is a matrix with entries in $\mathbb{H}$, and $M^{\dagger}$ is the quaternion conjugate transpose of $M$.
Apologies for the lengthy description, any help or comment will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

$Sp(n)\subseteq SU(2n)$ is clear in general, see this post, referring to John Stillwell's Naive Lie theory (in Fabian's answer).

I figured it out. The idea is, which way to take conjugate matters. Unlike the Hermitian inner product, some authors use the definition $\langle u,v \rangle = \bar{u}^{T}v$ while others use $\langle u,v \rangle = u^{T} \bar{v}$, without commutativity in $\mathbb{H}$, it's vital to have the correct form of the inner product in $\mathbb{H}^n$.
As for the one defined in Stillwell's book, $(p_1,...,p_n) \cdot (q_1,...,q_n)= p_1 \bar{q_1} + ... + p_n \bar{q_n}$, preservation of inner product by symplectic groups only makes sense when multiplication happens on the right. For the example in the question, given $u$ a unit quaternion, we have $(pu) \cdot (qu)=(pu)\overline{(qu)}=pu \bar{u} \bar{q}=p \bar{q}$, hence $Sp(1) = SU(2)$ as claimed.
In general, it's more convenient if we define the inner product on $\mathbb{H}^n$ the other way round: $(p_1,...,p_n) \cdot (q_1,...,q_n)= \bar{p_1} q_1 + ... + \bar{p_n} q_n$. In this case, $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{H})$ preserves the inner product iff $A^{\dagger}A=I$. The proof follows:
Suppose $A,B\in Mat_n(\mathbb{H})$, then $(AB)^{\dagger}_{ij}= \{(\overline{AB}) \}_{ji}=\overline{(AB)}_{ji}= \overline{(A_{jk}B_{ki})} =\bar{B}_{ki} \bar{A}_{jk}=B^{\dagger}_{ik} A^{\dagger}_{kj}=(B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger})_{ij}$, where the first equality is the $j,i$ element of the conjugate matrix of $(AB)$, and the second equality leads to the conjugate of the $j,i$ element of matrix $(AB)$.
So we still have $(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$ for quaternion matrices, despite NOT having $(AB)^T=B^TA^T.$ This is interesting and unexpected at first glance.
Therefore, $\langle Av, Aw \rangle= (Av)^{\dagger}(Aw)=v^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}Aw= v^{\dagger}w= \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $v,w \in \mathbb{H}^n$ iff $A^{\dagger}A=I$.
